# Is there a pythonic way to read tcsh csh shell wordlist variables

Tags: python, csh, tcsh

I am trying to read variables from cshell file output by an application.  The application assumes we are using cshell to read the variables.  I am using Python.
The file contains two (T)csh wordlist shell variables lnPARAM and lnVAL;

```
set lnPARAM = ('path' 'job' 'delete_source'                      )
set lnVAL   = ('/opt/genesis/fw/jobs/48039/input' '48039' 'no'   )
```

I would like to create variables for path, job and delete_source set to strings '/opt/..', '48039' and 'no'.
I have split the lines to a list;

```
>>> line0 = "set lnPARAM = ('path' 'job' 'delete_source'  )"
>>> line1 = "set lnVAL   = ('/opt/genesis/fw/jobs/48039/input' '48039' 'no' )"
>>> ln_param = [value.strip("'") for value in line0.split(' = ')[1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(' ') if value != '']
>>> ln_val = [value.strip("'") for value in line1.split(' = ')[1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(' ') if value != '']
>>> r = dict(zip(ln_param, ln_val))
>>> r['path']
'/opt/genesis/fw/jobs/48039/input'
```

shlex does not seem to be the solution.

```
>>>import shlex
>>> shlex.split(line0)
['set', 'lnPARAM', '=', '(path', 'job', 'delete_source', ')']
```

I am hoping someone else has a more elegant solution than the one I assembled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the string enclosed in parentheses before passing it to `shlex.split`:

```
import re
shlex.split(re.findall(r'\((.*)\)', line0)[0])
```